# Relational Data is Not Storing in Ebean

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, playframework, ebean

### Background

I am using the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)(Java) to store data. Play Framework uses
[Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/) to convert classes into data that can be stored in a database.

I am having issues creating `One To Many` database relationships. I am trying to create a relationship between a `User` model and a `UserEmail` model. Where each `User` may have many `UserEmails`.

[User Model Code](http://pastebin.com/61FzxvgV)
[User Email Model Code](http://pastebin.com/stgEAux7)

### The Issue

When I create a `User` and then add a `UserEmail`, it does not seam to save the `UserEmail` in the database. I have tried doing so many ways.

- By adding to the `List<UserEmail> emails` and then saving the `User`([Code](http://pastebin.com/fW8FEPQq))

  - **Result:** New `User` is stored in database with correct info, However no new `UserEmail` is stored in the database
- By creating a `static create` method in `UserEmail`([Code](http://pastebin.com/zyeSm1DY))

  - **Result:** No `UserEmail` was stored in the database
- By adding to the `List<UserEmail> emails` and then saving the `UserEmail` and the `User`([Code](http://pastebin.com/1RUTnkhe))

  - **Result:** New `User` is stored in database with correct info, However no new `UserEmail` is stored in the database

### Question

In [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)(Java), how do you create and store Relational Data? Is there some step I am missing? Do I have to add another `Annotation` to the `models` to make it work?

### Update

After some further testing it looks like saving the `User` object with a new `UserEmail` will save it to the database. However when I fetch a user

```
User retrievedTestUser = User.find.where().eq("userId", testUserId).findUnique();
```

It does not retrieve the `UserEmails`

Comment: what does retrievedTestUser.emails return? Null?

Comment: @Adil It returns empty, so `[]`.

Comment: could you add a mappedBy="user_tbl_name" value in the OneToMany annotation inside your User model? That may help

Comment: As you didn't explicitly 'eager fetch' the user emails (via fetch("emails")) the emails List will not be populated (via lazy loading) until you actually do something with it like call size() or try to iterate over the list.  Perhaps you should create a new question with the code showing the list is empty?

Comment: @Rob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746989/play-framework-relational-data-not-fetching

Answer (score 0):

Add information about *reverse* field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<UserEmail> emails;
```

[Details in documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29)

Comment: I tried adding the `mappedBy` attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation. With and without the `mappedBy` value the email and user was saved and accosated correctly. However when I tried to get the user ([code](http://pastebin.com/7Dk0ntQ4)) the user info was valid except the emails were blank. But the emails where properly stored in the database ([ScreenShot of UserEmail SQL Query Results](http://i.imgur.com/KSZRVsS.png)).

Answer (score 0):

Above problem was because there was `@Id` annotation missing in `UserEmail` class.
Adding below code solves the problem:

```
@Id
public String email;
```