# Relational Data is Not Fetching in Ebean

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, playframework, ebean

### Background

I am using [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)(Java) to store data. Play Framework uses [Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/) to convert classes into data that can be stored in a a database.

### Issue

I am currently having trouble fetching relational data completely. I have a `User` and a `UserEmail` model. The `User` can own multiple `UserEmail`s.

[User Model Code](http://pastebin.com/61FzxvgV)
[User Email Model Code](http://pastebin.com/stgEAux7)

When I try and fetch a `User`, the `User` data is fetched correctly, however the `UserEmail`s are not.

[Fetching Code](http://pastebin.com/uW8VVNsf)

When I specifically add `fetch("emails")` to the fetch code

```
User.find.fetch("emails").where().eq("userId", testUserId).findUnique();
```

It seams like it at least gets the emails. However when I try and show them via

```
return ok(Json.toJson(retrievedTestUser));
```

I get [This Error](http://pastebin.com/QmE34WGn)

### Question

Is there some way I can make Play Framework/Ebean automatically fetch the emails without adding `fetch("emails")` to every query? Maybe an annotation?

How do I resolve the error above? I get why it is thrown, but how can I fix it? Is there any way to have it only fetch one level deep?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution to above problem. Every entity should have id.
`User` class has field annotated with `@Id` but `UserEmail` has not.

After adding `@Id` annotation above `email` field of `UserEmail` class user is fetched properly and its email list is not empty.

```
@Id
public String email;
```

One more thing that I spotted in your code:
When you are creating bidirectional relation then you should use `mappedBy` attribute on one side to indicate that these are two ends of one relation and not two separate relations. So there should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Constraints.Required
public List<UserEmail> emails;
```